# Pronunciation of English "v"

Tags: pronunciation

Most sources on the Internet seem to indicate that English "v" in words like "vodka" or "raven" is /v/, identical to Polish "w" or Russian "в".

However, my pronunciation seems to differentiate between the two - I pronounce the Polish "w" as /v/ with a strong labiodental component, but English "v" is more of a /β/ sound, with lips puckered rather than touching the lower teeth. Trying to pronounce "vodka" with a Polish "w" feels unnatural and reminiscent of a sort of fake Russian accent.

Is it common for native English speakers to approximate "v" to some extent, or am I the one that's in the wrong here?

Comment: Unless there's some kind of physical impediment involved, *all* native Anglophones easily distinguish /v/ from /w/ (***vine*** and ***wine*** may be logically connected, but we never confuse the actual *words*). Just as we all distinguish /v/ from /b/ (something which probably seems really weird to *Spanish* speakers, who *don't* (can't?) distinguish between /v/ and /b/).

Comment: There are a dozen different ways "v" might be pronounced, depending on speaker and the particular word.  As FF suggests, the Spanish influence, particularly in the US, causes some of this.  English has been quite promiscuous in its adaptation of words and sounds from other languages and cultures.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Polish distinguishes easily between /v/ and /w/, or "w" and "ł", so I think that's not the issue here. The closest approximation to my pronunciation I could find is the Spanish "v", but slightly wider so that it's distinct from /b/.

Comment: When you say *Polish distinguishes easily between /v/ and /w/, or "w" and "ł"*, I think that implies you're assuming that those are 4 "distinct" phonemes - specifically, ***the same four phonemes*** in English and in Polish. But frankly I think that's highly unlikely. Some / all of them are probably just "close approximations" of counterparts between languages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry if it wasn't clear - I use /_/ for IPA and "_" for letters those phonemes are spelled with.

Comment: oic - well my point stands even if it should be ***2*** rather than ***4*** "different phonemes" (and/or ***allophones*** rather than ***phonemes***).

Comment: Almost all varieties of English pronounce the letter 'v' as a [voiced labiodental fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labiodental_fricative) or IPA /v/ and do not at all sound that letter with a [voiced bilabial fricative /β/ sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_bilabial_fricative). Also, for the [letter 'w' (a rounded voiced bilabial glide or similar semivowel)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labio-velar_approximant). In other words the English 'v' is nothing like a /β/ sound. I vaguely recall that maybe Welsh-English sometimes pronounces 'v' as /β/? Maybe?

Comment: As a native English speaker, the differences between v, w, and b all depend on the formation of the mouth. “V” is a soft letter sound requiring a humming sound deep in one’s throat while the lower teeth rest against the upper lip throughout its entire pronunciation. “B” is a hard letter sound requiring a momentary meeting (contact) of the top and bottom lip at the very beginning of its pronunciation. “W” is a soft letter sound requiring the momentary forming of a tight o (circle) with one’s mouth without the lips or teeth meeting at the very beginning of the pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

“Labiodental” refers to a consonant made with contact between the lower lip and the *upper* teeth. This is the case for me in “raven”. [v] therefore seems like a good transcription for English /v/.

“Bilabial” refers to a consonant made with contact between the lower lip and the upper lip. Spanish uses a bilabial fricative or approximant [β] for v and b (which are both pronounced the same) between vowels, and a bilabial plosive [b] for v and b after a nasal (as in -nv- or -mb-). I’m wondering whether you may have flipped around the meaning of [v] and [β].

I certainly don’t use anything closer to [β] in “raven”.